# No Output in QGIS 3.16.11 with previously working model and plugin

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-plugins, qgis-modeler

I have a model and also a bespoke plugin (fairly basic) which has been working in QGIS 3 ever since I can remember and I often update to the latest LTR.

Since updating to QGIS 3.16.11 my model no longer provides the specified output (the output of the model does not appear in the layers panel after completion). My plugin does spit out the specified output but the table is empty.

I wonder if this is a known bug (I can't find anything on Github) or if anyone has an idea as to why this might be happening?